# Как сохранить образ docker

Tags: node.js, docker

С помощью команды docker save "image" > "path".tar образ сохраняется, но весит очень много, около 2Гб, а также не открывается с ошибкой "Файл имеет неверный формат или поврежден"

Мой Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 3000

COPY package.json ./

RUN npm install 

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
      build:
        context: ./APP
      container_name: front
      ports:
        - '3000:3000'
      volumes:
        - .:/APP
```

Возможно ли, что образ выгружается вместе со всеми зависимостями в виде ОС и тд, если да, то как выгрузить образ без этих зависимостей?

Comment: а зачем? и как вы пытаетесь его открыть, что получаете ошибку "Файл имеет неверный формат или поврежден"?

Comment: Образ нужно развернуть на другой системе, а открыть я его пытался винраром и 7zip

Comment: для этих целей обычно используют docker registry, например docker hub или любой другой, но даже если вы хотите использовать docker save, то на другой машине нужно просто использовать docker load и все, а уменьшить образ можно с помощью multistage build

Comment: 2 gb - это как-то очень много. Я собрал небольшое приложение в докере на образе `node:18-alpine`, и получил всего 172 мб, а после сжатия gzip и вовсе 50 мб. Вы уверены, что ничего лишнего не тащите в образ инструкцией `COPY . .`?

Answer (score 0):

Да, `image save` выгружает образ целиком, включая базовый образ. Восстановить образ из архива командой `image load`

У вас получается архив размером 2 Гб? Это очень странно. Базовый образ всего 174 мб, сжатием `gzip` получается 50 мб.

Я сделал маленький образ

```
FROM node:18-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 8081

COPY ./src .

CMD ["node", "hello.js"]
```

В `./src` лежит единственный файл `hello.js`

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8081);

console.log('Server started at http://localhost:8081/');
```

```
docker build . -t try-node
```

Результат:

```
docker image ls
REPOSITORY                      TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
try-node                        latest              4445087d824e        13 minutes ago      175MB
```

Выгрузка:

```bash
docker image save try-node | gzip > image.tar.gz
du -sm image.tar.gz
```

```
50      image.tar.gz
```

Итого - выгруженный сжатый образ размером 50 мегабайт.

Восстановление образа:

```
$ docker image rm try-node
$ cat image.tar.gz | gzip -d | docker image load
f1417ff83b31: Loading layer [==================================================>]  7.338MB/7.338MB
8f90faa0eb99: Loading layer [==================================================>]  164.2MB/164.2MB
e2ed77d8fead: Loading layer [==================================================>]  7.819MB/7.819MB
1e9663a5b8eb: Loading layer [==================================================>]  3.584kB/3.584kB
03429486714c: Loading layer [==================================================>]  3.072kB/3.072kB
242deab87f84: Loading layer [==================================================>]  3.584kB/3.584kB
Loaded image: try-node:latest
```

Образ загружен и добавлен в список образов:

```
docker image ls try-node
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
try-node            latest              4445087d824e        25 minutes ago      175MB
```

Comment: https://rakiabensassi.substack.com/p/why-node_modules-are-the-heaviest